# Redirect the output of help() function's content to a file

Tags: python, pydoc

I am learning selenium and intend to check methods available.

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(start_url)
help(browser)
```

The help document is too long so I'd like to copy them to a file.

```
In [19]: with open("webdriver.md", "w") as file:
    ...:     file.write(help(browser))
    ...:     

TypeError: write() argument must be str, not None
```

Either pydoc is not helpful

```
In [23]: pydoc.writedoc("browser")
No Python documentation found for 'browser'.
Use help() to get the interactive help utility.
Use help(str) for help on the str class.
```

How could I write help(browser) to a plain text file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[bulit-in `help()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.3/Lib/site.py#L372-L373) is [a wrapper around `pydoc.Helper`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.3/Lib/_sitebuiltins.py#L88-L103), it writes to `stdout` by [default](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.3/Lib/pydoc.py#L1841-L1843), you could temporarily redirecting `sys.stdout` to a file:

```
>>> import contextlib
>>> with contextlib.redirect_stdout(open('browser_help.txt', 'w')):
...     help(browser)
```

or you could call `pydoc.Helper` directly, :

```
>>> import pydoc
>>> with open('browser_help.txt', 'w') as f:
...     h = pydoc.Helper(output=f)
...     h(browser)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to change the current stdout:

```
import sys
sys.stdout = open('webdriver.md', 'w')
help(browser)
```

Starting from **Python 3.4**, you can also use [`contextlib.redirect_stdout`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout):

```
from contextlib import redirect_stdout
with redirect_stdout(open('webdriver.md', 'w')):
    help(browser)
```

Comment: impressive, but it's not working in Ipython (perfectly good in standard ide)